# Are there any rules of ghusl al mayit if the person died in a dry area?

Tags: practical-islam, death, ghusl

We know that in Islam once we have no water present and we did effort to search for it, we are allowed to do tayamum instead of wudu' (ritual purification) for prayer or even ghusl al-janabah (bathing/washing after intercourse). But does this also apply in case of death?

I mean assuming a situation like if a person died in a desert and those who accompanied that person couldn't find water, what should they do?

I hope you can provide me some referenced answers with a practical solution how this ghusl would/could be performed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question.. The ruling for the deceased who died in a dry area is to perform **Tayammum** on him, since Tayammum **replaces** the functionality of water (**performing ablution or ghusl al-janabah**) when it is not available.

Here are the two verses that talked about Tayammum in Surat An-Nisaa and Surat Al-Ma'idah

[image]

[image]

You can also check this [answer](https://islamqa.info/en/39288) regarding your question.

Comment: Could you add an explanation on how this taymum would be performed, as this is my major Issue? As i know tyamum for a person who is able to do it, but how somebody does taymum for somebody else!

Comment: Check out this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ovgS5oO55s)